# Modify default drupal 8 search results

Tags: 8, search

I am using **Drupal 8** default search and I don't want to use **search api** module. Default search is working fine. But I Want to modify it. I want to categorize search result and get count of that category. Also I want to add class of that category so that On click of that category, I can hide other results.

There was hook `hook_preprocess_search_results()`  in `7` but in `8` I think they have removed.

So is there any alternate hook available? Is there any other way around without using search api and facet api?

Comment: It literally sounds like facets, why don’t you want to use facets?

Comment: Hook `hook_preprocess_search_results` works in D8. Please check out this article: http://fivemilemedia.co.uk/blog/how-do-you-change-drupal-8-search-results

Comment: You have to alter the route defined by the search module [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625840/drupal-8-core-search-module-change-markup/44522792#44522792)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a view with exposed filters may be a quicker solution for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add search behavioral and modify the results which it gives you, you can use [hook_node_search_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_search_result/8.4.x) , Else if you want to modify the look and design of your result items you can use [search-result.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21templates%21search-result.html.twig/8.4.x) file to theme the output markup of your result items.